# How to add a property to an EntityType after it has been added to the Data Store?

Tags: breeze

I have an Entity Framework Code First model with a column that is not mapped which I still want to persist between the server and the client. The model looks similar to this with many more properties:

```
public class OwnerInformation
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(16)]
    public byte[] SSNEncrypted { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [MaxLength(9)]
    [MinLength(9)]
    public string SSN { get; set; }
}
```

When the metadata is retrieved by Breeze SSN is not part of it, but when the data is sent over the wire the SSN is there. I would like to let breeze deal with the mapping through the metadata, but I would like to be able to still pass SSN between the client and the server and track it's state as I need to encrypt it before it is saved to the DB.

I tried adding it after the metadata is fetched like this:

```
var ownerType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType('OwnerInformation');
var sSN = new breeze.DataProperty({
  name: 'sSN',
  dataType: breeze.DataType.String,
  isNullable: false,
  maxLength: 9
});
ownerType.addProperty(sSN);
```

but I get the error: `The 'OwnerInformation:#Models' EntityType has already been added to a MetadataStore and therefore no additional properties may be added to it.`

Maybe I'm overthinking this and there is an easier way. I'm opened to any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took a different approach and decided to change the metadata at runtime on the server. Here's how I did it.

```
public class MyContextProvider : EFContextProvider<MyContext>
{
  protected override string BuildJsonMetadata()
  {
    string metadata = base.BuildJsonMetadata();
    JObject json = JObject.Parse(metadata);
    var entityOwnerInfo = json["schema"]["entityType"].Children().Where(j => (string)j["name"] == "OwnerInformation").SingleOrDefault();
    var propertyArray = entityOwnerInfo["property"] as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray;

    JToken ssnPropertyType = JToken.Parse(@"{
      ""name"": ""SSN"",
      ""type"": ""Edm.String"",
      ""fixedLength"": ""true"",
      ""maxLength"": ""9"",
      ""minLength"": ""9"",
      ""nullable"": ""false""}");
    propertyArray.Add(ssnPropertyType);

    return json.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's working! Now I can submit the [NotMapped] fields to the server with Breeze.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's a really good question.  Breeze doesn't currently support modifying an EntityType after it has been added to the MetadataStore.  But with your scenario I see the use case and I like your workaround.

I will add a feature request that allows this to be done more easily. Not sure yet exactly what this will look like, but...  Thanks for the scenario.

Comment: Whew. That was some nifty hackery by Jonas. As Jay says, we've been talking about relaxing the rule that says "you can't change the EntityType once it has been added to metadata". Now we have another data point.

Comment: If you have this need, here's the User Voice request: https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4293820-give-the-developers-more-extensibility-on-the-meta