# breezejs: adding referential constraint to an entity type

Tags: javascript, odata, breeze

This is a follow-up question to [my previous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512278/breezejs-navigation-property-not-added-to-entity) - this one was getting a bit messy and is more related to the Telerik Data Service.

The metadata I receive from the server are missing the referential constraints in the association node, **although I've set the foreign key attribute on my model**.

Therefore I was thinking about manually adding these constraints to my entities in the callback of FetchMetadata.

Is that possible and can someone provide a simple example on how to do it ?

**[EDIT]**

Here's what I have so far:

```
  manager.fetchMetadata().then(function () {
        var mandatType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Mandate");
        mandatType.autogeneratedKeyType = breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity;

        var openPositionsProp = new breeze.NavigationProperty({
            name: "OpenPositions",
            entityTypeName: "OpenPositions:#DirectDebitModel", 
            isScalar: true,
            associationName: "OpenPosition_Mandate_Mandate_OpenPositions",
            foreignKeyNames: ["Id"]
        });

        mandatType.addProperty(openPositionsProp);
});
```

But it raises the exception:

`The 'Mandate:#DirectDebitModel' EntityType has already been added to a MetadataStore and therefore no additional properties may be added to it.`

Comment: Are you trying to create a model reference between the entities?  AKA are you trying to manually create the navigation properties when loading up the meta data?

Comment: That's the idea, yes. Since the ReferentialConstraint node is missing from the metadata, I would like to be able to create the navigation properties on the fly right after I've fetched the metadata. Do you know how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have a possible approach that you might be able to use right now.

1. Fetch the metadata from Teleriks OData feed just like you do now.
2. Export the metadataStore created as a result of the previous step via the *MetadataStore.exportMetadata* method.  This will return "stringified" json for the same metadata in Breeze's native format. This format is much easier to work with.
3. Convert this string to json via *JSON.parse*.
4. Modify the json to add referential constraint information. See [Breeze Native Metadata format docs here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-metadata-format)
5. Create a new MetadataStore and import the modified json into it.
6. Create a new EntityManager with this MetadataStore and use it. This EntityManager should now have complete Breeze metadata for use with the rest of the feed.

   Hope this makes sense!

   We are planning on releasing a form of hybrid metadata in the next release. Unfortunately, it doesn't cover your case because we are focusing on how to add custom metadata to an existing metadataStore, and not actually edit/modify the existing metadata.

   Another alternative is that we (IdeaBlade) do offer consulting for this type of work.  We could probably write a tool that does steps 1 thru 6 for you.  Please contact breeze@ideablade.com if this is of interest and mention this post.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Firstly, when you say that 'you are focusing on how to add custom metadata to an existing metadataStore', is this not what I want ? I mean the referencial constraints are not even there, so it's an Add and not an Edit, right ?  If not, then your solution is probably the best card I have for now, although it sounds like a real pain to implement. My last hope is to be able to convince my manager to ditch OpenAccess and to use EF instead (why was OpenAccess invented if it does less.... :(  Thanks anyway !

Comment: Our first pass at "custom" metadata is intended to support extending the existing metadata structures, meaning metadata that describes information that is not already covered by existing metadata. For example, a display name for a property, or a custom description about the encoding for some binary data blob. Is there some reason why the 6 steps above will not work for you?

Comment: I see, these additions will be great indeed but like you said it's not going to fix my problem for now. The 6 steps are not too bad, it's just time consuming and I'm having other issues with OpenAccess and ODATA, so I've reached a point where I'm seriously considering to push everyone in the team to use EF instead.

Comment: Finally I have implemented your solution. I've exported the metadata, added the navigation properties and recreated the EntityManager. It works like a charm... except that now I'm facing the same issue as the one I've reported a few days ago here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060244/breezejs-navigation-property-is-created-but-not-filled-with-data         Note that this was with EntityFramework but now I'm using OpenAccess. In both cases the data is returned from the server, but breeze does not add it to the navigation properties. That really looks like a bug in breezejs, no ?

Comment: Does your navigation property metadata contain nodes for both     "associationName" and "foreignKeyNames"?

Comment: Ok, I've got to admit I'm confused. Everything looks good, but I can't repro the issue. So... my next suggestion is to build a sample model with pure EF that has the nav props correctly defined such that EF itself can navigate bidirectionally.  Next expose your EF model to Breeze via WebApi and then export the metadata.  Compare this metadata to your "manually" extended metadata and see if you can see any diffs. The other alternative is to contact "breeze@ideablade.com" and ask for consulting help on this. We have a professional services arm that specializes in this kind of issue.

Comment: I have made some progress on this. See my new answer below. Hopefully this will give you more insight !

Comment: Just an idea but "invForeignKeyNames" are only needed if you have a special kind of "unidirectional" navigation. Could you try to make this navigation bidirectional and see if this "fixes" the problem.

Comment: It's already a bidirectional property, it wouldn't work with WebApi otherwise, would it ? I have you looked at my reply below ? Is it not strange that for classic ODATA the navigation property results come back as an object instead of an array ? As a side note, what is the comment about ? What is __deferred in ODATA ? Could it be that I'm in this case ?

Comment: Ok, I've set the foreignKeyNames property instead of the inForeignKeyNames property as per your recommendation.  But it does not change anything, the same test fails (` if (!Array.isArray(relatedRawEntities)) return null;`) As long as the releatedRawEntities is not an array, it will always return null and fail to populate the navigation property.

Comment: please, Jay take a look at my latest reply. I've done my best to explain what's going on.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to mark this as the answer because the original question was How to add navigation properties to metadata. And this works, so I'm going to close this and carry on the conversation here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060244/breezejs-navigation-property-is-created-but-not-filled-with-data

Answer (score 1):

So you are getting meta data but it doesn't have a relationship between the entities.  Hmm I have not gotten metaData AND tried to create additional model properties that are related.

Your best bet is to add a property that is a navigation type on the constructor.

http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityType.html#method_addProperty

If it were me, I would try it this way (or something similar) inside of the constructor -

```
myEntity.addProperty({
                associatedEntity: {
                    entityTypeName: "AssociatedEntity", isScalar: true,
                    associationName: "AssociatedEntity_MyEntitys", foreignKeyNames: ["associatedEntityId"]
                }
            });
```

Where myEntity is the name of the current entity, AssociatedEntity would be your navigation property, the associatedEntityId is a property of myEntity that refers to the other entity.  Of course to have this be a two-way relationship you would need to add a property to AssociatedEntity as well.

```
associatedEntity.addProperty({
                myEntitys: {
                    entityTypeName: "MyEntity", isScalar: true,
                    associationName: "AssociatedEntity_MyEntitys", foreignKeyNames: ["myEntityId"]
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks. I have attempted to do just that (I'm only trying to add one side of the association for now). But I've got an exception - see edit of my original post. I guess it's too late at this stage for adding the navigation property, but where else could I add it ?

Comment: well actually after digging a bit more, it seems impossible at the moment to modify entity types once they've been added to the metadatastore :(    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118091/how-to-add-a-property-to-an-entitytype-after-it-has-been-added-to-the-data-store

Comment: Sorry my answer was more of a guess that I didn't have the time to explore further.

Comment: nothing wrong with that, you've actually pointed me into the right direction and it seems that this feature was already in the pipe of breeze team :)