# Breeze does not replace the Ref: node with its real data

Tags: javascript, json, breeze

How to force breeze to load the real Node data instead of something like `Object {$ref: "5"}`?
This happens all the time except for one of my extended properties that I created in my Client side code.

The raw JSON has this part:

```
CurrentUserAssignments: [
{
$ref: "5"
}
],
```

which never gets referred  to the node 5, which is also included in raw JSON results.

Here is part of  my EF Entity:

```
 public class Task
    {
        public Guid Id {get; set;}

         private  ICollection<Assignment> _assignments;
        public virtual ICollection<Assignment> Assignments
        {
            get { return _assignments ?? (_assignments = new Collection<Assignment>()); }
            set{_assignments = value;}
        }

        [NotMapped]
        public Assignment CurrentUserAssignments
        {
            get
            {
                var userId = Guid.Parse(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('$'[1]);
               return Assignments.OrderByDescending(a=>a.AssignmentDate).Take(1).SingleOrDefault(p => p.AssigneeId == userId && p.IsRevoked == false && p.Invisible == false);


            }
        }
....
}
```

and in the client I registered the CurrentUserAssignments in Task Constractor
something like:

```
store.registerEntityTypeCtor(models.entityNames.task, function () { this.NoteCount = 0; this.IsDone = false; this.CurrentUserAssignments = ko.observable() });
```

but CurrentUserAssignments is never get full with real data but only `ref:'5'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.extend` on client or `.Include` on server side for real data. When server returns $ref, that means that the object has been sent before and it has been given an unique identifier.

Instead of sending same object over and over again, server knows there is an object with unique identifier and can then just send $ref instead of real object. Breeze is capable of parsing this and can replace $ref with real object that has been sent before.

The only thing you need to do is ask breeze to include that object into "main" object using either .expand or .Include on client or server side.

You can read some details about $ref in breeze here: http://breeze.github.io/doc-cs/webservice-data-mapping.html

Just search for $ref, there is description below.

Comment: I Included the Property by sending it as expand to the server.and as you said the data is loaded and I can see all the data in the json result ... but  when I am trying to use the data in Knockout binding it's returning the ref:5.it is not replaced with it's real data. I have read the link you provided but it just explained how breeze doing the replacement (traversing) which is not happening in my case. is there any way to force breeze to do that? it may worth to mentioned that this property is a [notmaped] property in EF model, and i added to type contractor in Breeze.am I missing something?

Comment: I believe it is worth mentioning that this property is a [notmaped] property because in Breeze docs there is a sentence: "Breeze can create an entity based exclusively on its metadata description". If your property is not mapped, it will not be reckognized by Breeze. You can see workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118091/how-to-add-a-property-to-an-entitytype-after-it-has-been-added-to-the-data-store

Comment: Thanks you very mush for your answers
I edited the Question.
can you give me your final thoughts.

Comment: You added an observable, but you certainly didn't register the C# object. You will need to modify metadata as in the link I sent you.

Answer (score 1):

Why is "CurrentUserAssignments' marked with a [NotMapped] attribute?

Comment: good catch, missed that one! But I guess he figured it out ;)