# Breeze.js: How to include all related data in payload even if it was sent

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, odata, breeze

I have a list of of data being return from a "standard" HttpGet IQueryable method from an ApiController that implements the Breeze EFContextProvider. When one of the objects references another object that has already been returned in the payload, Breeze gives me an $ref to refer to the object that was already returned.

I want the object with all related objects return explicitly, not a reference with $ref. Also, I'm not using the breeze.js library on the client side; simply making straight calls to the Controller with a web address.

I found this:

[Breeze does not replace the Ref: node with its real data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172906/breeze-does-not-replace-the-ref-node-with-its-real-data)

which is the thing I'm looking for, but using Include on the server still doesn't return all of the data.

Any idea on how to "force" Breeze on the server side to include all related data no matter if it was returned and referenced in the payload?

**Update 1**

Per Steve's answer below I added the following to the BreezeWebApiConfig.RegisterBreezePreStart method in the App_Start folder:

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Object;
```

Compiling and running produces the same output with only the $ref group instead of the full data. I'm sending a request to the server to $expand the collection. Do I need to change the SerializerSettings upon each request to the controller or will adding this to the BreezeWebApiConfig.RegisterBreezePreStart method be enough?

**Update 2**

I've added a CustomBreezeConfig class per the instructions at the link that Steve added in his answer. I am however using Breeze.WebApi2 so it appears that the BreezeConfig is actually in Breeze.ContextProvider. The code compiles, but I'm still seeing the same $ref for the actual object in JSON.

Do I need to include this CustomerBreezeConfig class in a specific place in my project for Breeze to use it's serializer settings?

Comment: Sorry, I left out the Breeze-specific configuration info, which is important if you're using the `[BreezeController]` attribute.  I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Under WebAPI, Breeze uses the [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) serializer to turn the results to JSON.  You can change the serializer settings (specifically the [PreserveObjectReferences](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm) setting) to change this behavior.

Breeze configures it's own JSON serializer, so in a Breeze app, you'll need to configure it as described in the [Breeze Web API Controller doc](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-api-controller).

Note that, if you turn PreserveObjectReferences off, you might also need to configure the [ReferenceLoopHandling](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/SerializationSettings.htm) setting, if you have circular reference in your object graphs (as most of us do).